# Show that the area of ​triangle $S_{ABC} = R\times MN$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Show that the area of ​​triangle $ABC = R\times MN(R=BO)$

I can't demonstrate this relationship

[image]

My progress:

$$S_{\triangle ABC} = \frac{abc}{4R}$$
$$S_{\triangle ABC}=\frac{AC\times BH}{2}$$

$BMHN$ is cyclic

Therefore $\angle HMN \cong\angle HBN\\
\angle MBH \cong \angle MNH\\$

$\triangle AMH \sim \triangle AHB\\ 
\triangle CNH \sim \triangle CHB$

...?

Comment: When you say $ABC = R.MN(R=BO),$ do you mean $ABC = R \cdot MN(R=BO)$

Comment: @EricArcherman  I didn't understand your doubt.. the statement is very clear  the area of ​​triangle $ABC=R.MN(R=BO)$

Comment: Sorry for not making this clear but I was wondering what does the period mean between the $R$ and $MN?$

Comment: @EricArcherman multiplication

Comment: Use law of sines in the cyclic quadrilateral $BMHN$ to deduce that $MN = BH \times \sin \angle ABC$.

Comment: Is $BO$ extended to $MN$ a right-angle, or is it an illusion in this example?

Comment: @JMP You can in fact prove that $BO \perp MN$.

Comment: @petaarantes Use `\cdot` instead of `.` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First establish that $MN = BH \times \sin \angle ABC$

([law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) - $\sin (\angle HMB):BH = \sin (\angle ABC):MN$).

Then,

$\triangle AOC$ is isosceles, let $\angle OAC=\angle OCA = \beta$.

Then $\angle AOC = 180^\circ - 2\beta = 180^\circ - \alpha-\gamma$.

where $\alpha,\gamma$ are the appropriate angles from the isosceles triangles $\triangle AOB$ and $\triangle BOC$.

The perpendicular from $O$ through $AC$ divides the angle in two, i.e. $90^\circ - \alpha-\gamma$, and so we arrive at $AC=R\times \sin (\angle ABC)$.

Comment: you need demonstrate that $MN=BH\cdot sin\angle ABC$

Comment: @petaarantes; i've added it.

Answer (score 2):

Hints for a geometric solution:

-Draw a circle radius $R$ center on B, it intersect altitude BH at E.

-Connect N to E and extend it to meet a circle center on N and radius MN at F. It can be seen that NF is parallel with AC, so it is perpendicular on BH at point E. So $FN=MN$. We have:

$S_{ABC}=S_{BFN}+S_{ACNF}=\frac{R\times FN}2+\frac{(FN+AC)(BH-R)}2$

which finally gives:

$R\times FN=FN\times BH-R\times FN + AC\times BH-AC\times R$

Or:

$2R\times FN=AC\times BH$

if you prove:

$AC\times R=FN\times BH$

Comment: Thanks for soluton

Answer (score 1):

The orthocenter and the circumcenter of a triangle are isogonal conjugates, therefore
$\angle ABH=\angle NBO=α\\
HMBN(cyclic)\implies \angle BHM=\angle MNB=90−α\\
\therefore  \angle BFN = 90^0 \implies BO\perp MN \\
[BMON]=[BMN]−[MNO]=\frac{BO⋅MN}{2}=\frac{R⋅MN}{2}(I)\\
\triangle MBN \sim \triangle CBA \therefore  \frac{MN}{MB}=\frac{b}{a} \\
∠MHB=90−(90−∠A) \implies MB=BHsen(\angle A)\\
[BMON]=\frac{R⋅ba⋅BH⋅sen(\angle A)}{2}=\frac{[ABC]⋅Rsen(∠A)}{a}=\frac{[ABC]}{2}(II)\\
(I)=(II):\frac{[ABC]}{2}=\frac{R.MN}{2} \implies \boxed{[ABC]=R.MN}
$
[image]

(Solution by FelipeM.)